# Find the nearest rectangle intersection point on a line

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, physics

I have a line projecting out from a location `x_o` and `y_o` at a direction of `theta`. The world is not infinite and has a border.

I want to find the first rectangle that's hit by the line and the intersection point.

This is a typical 2D game programming problem, but is there any brief paper/tutorial that I can read? I'm having trouble with the search terms.

Edit: I know about raycasting. Is there any very simple implementations that I could take a look at? Also is there any analytical way to solve this efficiently. Lastly, is there any generalizations that I could make without resorting to only rectangles (like an rotated rectangle.., circle etc)

Edit2: Also open to good, efficient data structures to store the map and the obstacles

Comment: How are the rectangles given?

Comment: I also have tile-based stuff... Actually the tile based stuff are the main proportion.. and there are some rectangles

Answer (score 0):

How about you partition your world in a grid. In every cell, store the obstacles that lie completely or partly in this cell. This will be your search structure.

Shooting a ray R from (xo, yo) in direction theta, then, starts with locating the cell that contains (xo, yo). Next, calculate the intersection between R and the cell (i.e. where R leaves the cell), and depending on which side R leaves the cell, make that neighbouring cell your new current cell. For this cell too, calculate where R leaves it, etc.

In each cell that you reach, check if R collides with any of the obstacles stored in this cell, and if so, your ray has collided with an obstacle and you can stop traversing cells.

Obviously, this requires that you make the cells of your grid small enough so that they each contain only a small number of obstacles. If the size of your obstacles varies a lot, you could consider using a [Quadtree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) rather than a regular grid. This will make traversing the cells more complicated, though.

Answer (score 0):

You may gain some traction by defining your obstacle rectangles as nodes and edges. Each corner is a point (a node), and each side is an edge. Given your collection of nodes you can generate linear equations for the edges.

Then, with your known equation for your ray, determine if there is a simultaneous solution between the ray and each edge. If there is, that edge is a candidate for a collision at the solution point.

Now, these edge equations are the full line... the side of your rectangle is just a segment of that line, not the entire line. So...

Finally, you can determine if the solution point is contained on the edge segment (does it lie within the two nodes). If it does, then the candidate edge is an actual collision edge. If more than one collision edge is found, just take the one whose solution point is closest to the origin of the ray.